# Deja-Dup failure: No space left

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Deja-Dup failed with message ¨No space left¨. The destination of the backup is a cloud service that, I discovered after some poking around, has an upper limit to the number of files in a single directory. I was hitting this limit.

Is there any way to either

- let Deja-Dup use more than one target directory

or

- increase the size of each archive file (current value seems to be around 25 MB)

or

- any other suggestion to resolve the problem.

I realize that I could probably work directly with duplicity, by-passing Deja-Dup altogether, but that looks rather complicated, and I am scared of not doing it right, rendering my backup useless.